# How can I ensure I get a currency value when using an InputBox in Outlook?

Tags: vba, outlook, currency

I am trying to get a value from an InputBox that is a currency (comma every three digits and two decimals.

When I put **12345.60** in to the InputBox I get **12345.6** out. I was expecting to get **12,345.60** instead.

Below is a stripped down version of my code.

```
Public Sub MoneyTest()
Dim MoneyInput       As Currency

MoneyInput = InputBox("What is the Money Input ?")

Set objMsg = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

With objMsg

.HTMLBody = MoneyInput

.Display
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`InpoutBox` returns a string, how you format that string is up to you. You can try to use [FormatCurrency](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/formatcurrency-function) function

[image]

Comment: This did the job. Once I wrapped my variable in the FormatCurrency function for the output it did exactly what I wanted.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The `InputBox` function displays a prompt in a dialog box, waits for the user to input text or click a button, and returns a string containing the contents of the text box.

```
Public Sub MoneyTest()
Dim MoneyInput As String

MoneyInput = InputBox("What is the Money Input ?")

Set objMsg = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

With objMsg

.HTMLBody = "<html><body>" & MoneyInput & "</body></html>"

.Display

End With
End Sub
```

Another aspect is that you should create a well-formed HTML markup string before assigning it to the `HTMLBody` property to avoid any formatting.